# ARM Assembler NEON - Increasing performance

Tags: android, performance, assembly, arm, neon

I have converted part of an algorithm from C to ARM Assembler (using NEON instructions),
but now it is 2x slower than the original C Code.
How can I improve performance?

Target is a ARM Cortex-A9.

The algorithm reads 64Bit-values from an array. From this value one byte is extracted, which is then used as the lookup-value for another table. 
This part is done about 10 times, and each resulting table value is XOR´d with the others and the final result written into another array.

Something like this:

```
result[i] = T0[ GetByte0( a[i1] ) ] ^ T1[ GetByte1( a[i2] ) ] ^ ... ^ T10[ (...) ];
```

In my approach i load the whole array "a" in Neon Registers and then move the right byte in an arm register, calculate the offset and then load the value from the table:

```
vldm.64 r0, {d0-d7}         //Load 8x64Bit from the input array

vmov.u8 r12, d0[0]          //Mov the first Byte from d0 into r12
add r12, r2, r12, asl #3    // r12 = base_adress + r12 << 3
vldr.64 d8, [r12]           // d8 = mem[r12]
.
.
.
veor d8, d8, d9             // d8 = d8 ^ d9
veor d8, d8, d10            // d8 = d8 ^d10      ...ect.
```

Where r2 holds the base adress of the lookup table.

```
adress = Table_adress + (8* value_fromByte);
```

This step (except the loading at the beginning) is done like 100 times. Why is this so slow?

Also what are the differences between **"vld"**, **"vldr"** and **"vldm"** - and which one is the fastest.
How can i perform the offset calculation only within Neon registers?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your C code matches the description. The C is XORing multiple bytes of the same word, but the quesiton says each byte is used to index the next. We can't optimize code if you can't show it clearly.

Comment: Yes you are right. I edited it. It is always another word.

Comment: Neon may not be the way to optimize this.  The code is SIMD in the normal ARM instruction set.  You can use a 64k table (easily generated) and process 16bits at time and you can also run 32bit of EORs at once and fold the result.  The algorithm of getting a random index makes this memory bound so the code doing the EOR won't significantly affect things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try

```
ldrb     r12, [r0], #1
add      r3, r2, r12, asl #3
vld1.64  {d0}, [r3]

ldrb     r12, [r0], #1
add      r3, r2, r12, asl #3
vld1.64  {d1}, [r3]
veor     d0, d0, d1         // d8 = d8 ^ d1

ldrb     r12, [r0], #1
add      r3, r2, r12, asl #3
vld1.64  {d1}, [r3]
veor     d0, d0, d1         // d8 = d8 ^ d1

...
```

That will not be the best solution. After that you can increase performance by re ordering instruction.

Comment: Yes reordering will be the last part. I am trying it now with the ldrb instruction, but it seems it can´t load a byte from a .quad value. I define my lookup-table in assembler like this:
.global t0   

t0:   

.quad 0xc6a597f4a5f432c6   

.quad 0xf884eb9784976ff8   

but  ldrb r1, t0  fails.

why should i use "vld1.64" instead of "vldr.64" ?

Comment: This is probably the only way to do the actual lookup since the looked up values are 64-bit. The number of veor operations can be reduced however by doing them on the quad-registers. Load four looked up values into d0, d1, d2 and d3. Do veor q0, q0, q1 and then veor d0, d0, d1 and you will have done the XOR of four values in two operations.

Comment: With ldrb it is now a little bit faster than the C-Version. Do you have any tips on re-ordering the code to improve performance and/or AR/NEON pipelining in general?

Comment: Thank you - it looks very helpful. Is this also working for Cortex-A9? Maybe you can consider offering an english version too?

Answer (score 3):

Neon isn't very capable of dealing with Lookups larger than the VTBL instruction's limits(32bytes  if I remember correctly).
How's the lookup table created to start with? If it's just calculations, just let Neon do the math instead of resorting to lookups.
It will be much faster this way.

Comment: the lookup table is static & hardcoded. About 2000 64-Bit values.

Answer (score 2):

don't use

```
vmov.u8 r12, d0[0]
```

moving data from NEON register to the ARM register is the worst thing you can do.

Maybe you should see VTBL instruction !
What is you byte range 0..255 ?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will try to change that. What I am trying to archieve is this: I have a 2dimensional array (8x8 Byte). I need one different byte from every column. This byte-value is the index for another aray (64-Bit). So I need to get the right byte values, to lookup my values in the table and then XOR all the found values. I hope this is more or less understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with NEON "intrinsics". Basically they're C functions that compile down to NEON instructions. The compiler still gets to do all the instruction scheduling, and you get the other boring stuff (moving data about) for free.

It doesn't always work perfectly, but it might be better than trying to hand code it.

Look for `arm_neon.h`.